# How to get a pod's disk I/O read write in bytes in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

I was using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/) for monitoring a kubernetes cluster.
I want to know what is the disk read/write for each pod.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i have tried with metrics server. then kube-state-metrics (it is giving the values as zero for all pods)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you if you are using [nginx ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) you can configure it with:

```
enable-vts-status: "true"
```

This will give you a bunch of prometheus metrics for each pod that has on ingress. The metric names start with **nginx_upstream_**

In case it is the cronjob creating the spikes, install node-exporter daemonset and check the **metrics container_fs_**

Comment: i am using prometheus exporter and container_fs_ for all metrics showing zero

Comment: Did you follow propriately every single steps during exporter? Take a look: https://devconnected.com/monitoring-disk-i-o-on-linux-with-the-node-exporter/